# Selecting the column name into a field from another table based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-update

I have 2 tables that will match on a value, let's call it PersonID. Here are the tables:

```
Table1

ID   |   Field   |   Value
-----|-----------|--------
1    |   Loc1    |   faf  
1    |   Loc1    |   0653
2    |   Loc1    |   5711  
3    |   Loc1    |   9669
4    |   Loc1    |   ado  
4    |   Loc1    |   6843  
5    |   Loc1    |   rfc  
6    |   Loc1    |   cba 


Table2
ID   |   Loc1    |   Loc2
-----|-----------|--------
1    |   faf     |   0653  
2    |           |   5711
3    |           |   9669  
4    |   ado     |   6843  
5    |   rfc     |         
6    |   cba     |
```

I accidentally inserted the value `Loc1` for the Field in Table1. I need to update it based on the name of the colomn from Table2.

How can I update Table1 by searching for the Table1.Value column in Table2 and then taking the column name. I need it to end up looking like this:

```
ID   |   Field   |   Value
-----|-----------|--------
1    |   Loc1    |   faf  
1    |   Loc2    |   0653
2    |   Loc2    |   5711  
3    |   Loc2    |   9669
4    |   Loc1    |   ado  
4    |   Loc2    |   6843  
5    |   Loc1    |   rfc  
6    |   Loc1    |   cba
```

NOTE: All Loc2 values are not numbers and All Loc1 values are not letters. I just used those values for simplicity sake.

Comment: I am just looking to update Table1.Field so that it has the correct column name that it correlates to in Table2.

Comment: The ID column is not an identity column, it is just an ID for the person. So, John Smith would be ID 1, Jane Doe would be ID 2, and so forth.

Comment: `Table1.ID` is a foriegn key to `Table2.ID`, just normalise your data and delete `Table1.Field` and `Table1.Value`. If there is no other data in `Table1`, delete that too. If you don't want normalised data, don't use a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a basic `CASE` to determine which column in `Table2` contains the value referenced in the `value` column from `Table1`:

```
UPDATE t1
SET Field = 
CASE 
    WHEN t1.Value = t2.Loc1 THEN 'Loc1' 
    WHEN t1.Value = t2.Loc2 THEN 'Loc2' 
END
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

I'm assuming that this is simply a simplified version of your actual data / table structure, but something you might consider is that if these two tables are supposed to contain identical information, that you actually don't need both tables.

Instead could pivot or unpivot the data from either table in order to get the results in the other table's structure as needed.